# Issue with TensorWedge and TensorReduce?

Tags: bugs, tensors

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.3.1**

---

If I use `TensorReduce` on the result of `TensorWedge`:

```
$Assumptions = {a ∈ Vectors[dim], b ∈ Vectors[dim]};
TensorWedge[a, b]
TensorReduce[%]
TensorReduce[%]
```

I actually get

```
a \wedge b
1/2 a \wedge b
1/4 a \wedge b
```

Comment: A funny bug, this one: `Assuming[a ∈ Vectors[n] && b ∈ Vectors[n], Nest[TensorReduce, TensorWedge[a, b], 4]]`.

Comment: Seems to be a new bug in version 10 (I tested 10.2). This does not happen in version 9.

Comment: This is strange... we're looking into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There was a missing multinomial factor in the transformation rules that `TensorReduce` has for `TensorWedge`. This will be fixed in an upcoming version of *Mathematica*. Thank you for finding it!